# spring boot webflux login with username or email address

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to spring boot webflux, and am using Cassandra as my database. I can't figure it out how to login with username or email. I have three tables

user table

```
Create Table user (
   userid bigint,
   username text,
   password text,
   name text,
   email text,
   phone text,
   birthday text,
   biography text,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
```

user_username table

```
Create Table user (
   username text,
   userid bigint,
   password text,
   name text,
   email text,
   phone text,
   birthday text,
   biography text,
   PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

user_email table

```
Create Table user (
   email text,
   username text,
   userid bigint,
   password text,
   name text,
   phone text,
   birthday text,
   biography text,
   PRIMARY KEY (email)
)

@PostMapping("/signin")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> login(@RequestBody AuthLoginRequest authLoginRequest) {
   return userService.findByUsernameOrEmail(authLoginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail()).map((user) -> {
      if(passwordEncoder.encode(authLoginRequest.getPassword()).equals(user.getPassword())) {
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(tokenProvider.generateToken(user)));
      }else {
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
      }
   }.defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
}
```

This is where the issues comes in how will i return a user mono Mono . if they login with their username i have to query the user_username table or if they login with their email address i have to query the user_email table.

```
@Service
public class UserService() {
   public Mono<User> findByUsernameOrEmail(String usernameOrEmail) {

   }
}
```

Do i need to zip the user_username and user_email class? Please i need a solution i haven't seen any related issue concerning this. please i need a working solution.

Based on your answer @NikolaB i have edited this question to show what i have done so far

```
public Mono<User> findByUsernameOrEmail(String usernameOrEmail) {
  return userUsernameRepository.findById(usernameOrEmail)
     .map(userUsername -> {
                System.out.println("Checking name "+userUsername.getName());// i printed out the name of the user
                return new User(userUsername);
            }).switchIfEmpty(userEmailRepository.findById(usernameOrEmail)
                .map(userEmail -> {
                        System.out.println("Checking name " +userEmail.getName());// i printed out the name of the user
                        return new User(userEmail);
                    }));
}
```

Everything works well...

My user table

```
public class User {
    //My Constructors
    public User(UserUsername userUsername) {
      System.out.println("Userid " + userUsername.getUserId());/I am getting the userId
      User user = new User();
      BeanUtils.copyProperties(userUsername, user);
      System.out.println("New Userid " + user.getUserId()); //I am getting the userId
    }

    public User(UserEmail userEmail) {
      System.out.println("Userid " + userEmail.getUserId()); /I am getting the userId
      User user = new User();
      BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEmail, user);
      System.out.println("New Userid " + user.getUserId()); /I am getting the userId
    }
}
```

My post mapping

Here the User is empty

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> login(@RequestBody AuthLoginRequest authLoginRequest) {
   return userService.findByUsernameOrEmail(authLoginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail()).map((user) -> {
   if(passwordEncoder.encode(authLoginRequest.getPassword()).equals(user.getPassword())) {
          return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(tokenProvider.generateToken(user)));
      }else {
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
      }
   }.defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the `user_username` table and if there is an entry, map it to `User` class and return it. If there isn't you need to query the `user_email` table and map it to `UserUsername` class if an entry exists.

Easiest way to do it would be with repositories:

```
public interface UserUsernameRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserUsername, String> {
}


public interface UserEmailRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserEmail, String> {
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
@Service
public class UserService() {

   @Autowired
   private UserUsernameRepository userUsernameRepository;

   @Autowired
   private UserEmailRepository userEmailRepository;

   public Mono<User> findByUsernameOrEmail(String usernameOrEmail) {
       return userUsernameRepository.findById(usernameOrEmail)
               .switchIfEmpty(userEmailRepository.findById(usernameOrEmail)
                   .map(userEmail -> new UserUsername(userEmail))) // or some other way to map properties to UserUsername class
                   .map(userUsername -> new User(userEmail)) // or some other way to map properties to wanted User class
       }
    }
```

If both queries returned no results (empty) then service method would return `Mono.empty()` which is exactly what you need.

Note that you have to implement property mapping in `new UserUsername` and `new UserUsername` constructors.

**Edit**

Ok I think I know where the problem is, in the User constructors you are creating a new `User` instance and mapping `UserUsername/UserEmail` instance properties to that instantiated `User` instance when in fact that instance is not tied to instance which is returned by the constructor. Either set the fields manually in those constructors like this:

```
public User(UserUsername userUsername) {
      System.out.println("Userid " + userUsername.getUserId()); //I am getting the userId
      this.email = userUsername.getEmail();
      this.username = userUsername.getUsername();
      ...
}
```

or in the service method map with `BeanUtils`:

```
public Mono<User> findByUsernameOrEmail(String usernameOrEmail) {
  return userUsernameRepository.findById(usernameOrEmail)
     .map(userUsername -> {
                System.out.println("Checking name "+userUsername.getName());// i printed out the name of the user
                User user = new User();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(userUsername, user);
                return user;
            }).switchIfEmpty(userEmailRepository.findById(usernameOrEmail)
                .map(userEmail -> {
                        System.out.println("Checking name " +userEmail.getName());// i printed out the name of the user
                        User user = new User();
                        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEmail, user);
                        return user;
                    }));
}
```

Comment: i appreciate for the answer. I did what you said, i queried the the user_username and user_email table to check if there is an entry and it works. The problem i have is to map them to the user table if there is an entry which i did but i get an empty Mono from the user table, i needed to get the saved password and matched it with the inputted password. i used spring BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target) in the user class constructor.

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug reactive code, so it's difficult to say why you get empty mono. You are sure there is data in tables with the username or email you are using to test this code? Can you add log statements or System.out.print in findByUsernameOrEmail method in those two map statements and see what is returned from repository methods?

Comment: Please take a look at the edited question based on your asnwer

Comment: @ChristianIbanibo Added to my answer based on your new code.

Comment: the nightmare is over. I am so happy thank you i appreciate.